# ReferenceError: GM_xmlhttpRequest is not defined

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, referenceerror, gm-xmlhttprequest

I get a ReferenceError in the following userscript code:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name          ...
// @namespace     ...
// @description   ...
// @include       ...
// @grant         GM_xmlhttpRequest
// ==/UserScript==

console.log(GM_info);
try
{
    console.log(GM_xmlhttpRequest({ method: "GET", url: "http://google.ca/", synchronous: true }).readyState);
}
catch (e)
{
    console.log(e);
}
...
```

It first logs `GM_info` successfully, then logs the ReferenceError. (I'm using Firefox/Firebug.)

> ReferenceError: GM_xmlhttpRequest is not defined

Why do I get this error?

Comment: Can't duplicate.  What are your specs? (OS, FF version, GM version, etc.)  This is most likely due to an invalid metadata block.

Comment: Win7 SP1 x64, FF 21.0, GM 1.9. The metadata block is from [this file](https://ninjaecho.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#ninjaecho.user.js), with only `@grant` modified.

Comment: Tested on same system (less SP1).  No problem found.  Does your metadata block have leading whitespace?  Is the file encoded in anything but ANSI or UTF?  Pastebin the *exact* script that duplicates the problem.  Do step 4 from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16315994/331508).

Comment: A reinstall of the script fixed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reinstalling the script fixed the problem. I didn't need to restart Firefox, but it may be helpful for other people. [Brock's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16315994/785745) has helpful debugging tips for problems like this.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem, and what fixed it for me was adding this at the top:

```
// @grant        GM_xmlhttpRequest
```

Answer (score 9):

Since the news version (GM 4.0) this error happened when you use `GM_xmlhttpRequest` because `GM_xmlhttpRequest` was replaced by : `GM.xmlHttpRequest`.

The new code is :

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name          ...
// @namespace     ...
// @description   ...
// @include       ...
// @grant         GM.xmlHttpRequest
// ==/UserScript==

console.log(GM_info);
try
{
    console.log(GM.xmlHttpRequest({ method: "GET", url: "http://google.ca/", synchronous: true }).readyState);
}
catch (e)
{
    console.log(e);
}
//...
```

[Greasemonkey: "GM_xmlhttpRequest is not defined" with the new update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49365651/greasemonkey-gm-xmlhttprequest-is-not-defined-with-the-new-update/54456646#54456646)

Comment: Should have kept backwards compatibility. Absolutely moronic changes.

Comment: GM object's methods are async (as opposed to functions containing "_"). They will not slow down the page. Sometimes there is no progress without breaking something else. Do your new scripts the new way, for old scripts GM offered fast-fix. Just add: `// @require https://greasemonkey.github.io/gm4-polyfill/gm4-polyfill.js` [reference](https://github.com/greasemonkey/gm4-polyfill)